# Trying to find frequency of certain characters in a string but the results are very far off

Tags: c, arrays, char, frequency

I am trying to write a program which calculates and prints the GC content of a string of DNA(which is input through a txt file). That is, the percentage of G's and C's in a string of DNA. Here is my function for the GC percentage:

```
void updateGCCount(char s[], int *gc, int *at) {
   char c[MAXLENGTH];
   int i,GCcount,ATcount;
   float len,GCpercentage;
   GCcount=0;
   ATcount=0;
   for(i=0;c[i]!='\0';++i)
   {
     if(c[i]=='G' || c[i]=='C')
     {
       ++GCcount;
       *gc=GCcount;
     }
     if(c[i]=='A' || c[i]=='T')
     {
       ++ATcount;
       *at=ATcount;
     }
   }
   strcpy(c,s);
   len=strlen(c);
   GCpercentage=*gc/len;
   printf("GC-content: %.2f\n",GCpercentage);

}
```

This is my function definition, and the part which is supposed to correctly print the GC percentage is what I am not sure about. Below is my main program which utilizes the input text file.

```
#include "genomics.h"

int main(){
   char s[MAXLENGTH];
   int gc, at;
   scanf("%s",s);
   printf("Sequence  : %s\n",s);
   updateGCCount(s, &gc, &at);

   return 0;
}
```

Any help or advice on why I am not getting a correct value for the GCpercentage would be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you getting instead?

Comment: For example, if the DNA string is ATCGCGAT, I am getting 701019.00

Comment: there are some odd things in the code, most notably you scan vector `c` first, then `strcpy` the input `s` into it...

Comment: I realize that is a little weird, but that should not really affect anything...I could be wrong though

Comment: What is genomics.h in the question?

Comment: It most definitely should. Arrays declared inside functions are initialized with garbage data.

Comment: you are counting garbage

Comment: It just has the function declaration, the same as the definition. And also the defined MAXLENGTH value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing your tests on char array "c":

```
char c[MAXLENGTH];
...
for(i=0;c[i]!='\0';++i)
{
 if(c[i]=='G' || c[i]=='C')
 {
   ++GCcount;
   *gc=GCcount;
 }
 if(c[i]=='A' || c[i]=='T')
 {
   ++ATcount;
   *at=ATcount;
 }
```

}

If should be on s, the array that you passed in. The c array is probably superflous, you should be able to get the length from s as well

Comment: So are you saying I should just get rid of the char c[MAXLENGTH] array and change the c's to s's?

Comment: yeah that should do it

Comment: That worked for the strings that contain C's or G's, however when testing strings that do not have C's or G's, I get a rather large number rather than a 0, which I expect

Comment: If you do not enter either if-statement, then *at and *gc are also garbage values - initialize them.

Comment: That seemed to work perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`c` is not initialize, so `*gc` and `*at` are not updated at all and they contain garbage..

here you should use `s` instead of `c`

```
for(i=0;c[i]!='\0';++i)
   {
     if(c[i]=='G' || c[i]=='C')
     {
       ++GCcount;
       *gc=GCcount;
     }
     if(c[i]=='A' || c[i]=='T')
     {
       ++ATcount;
       *at=ATcount;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strongly un-idiomatic program.  Consider the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit(3) */

float count_gc(const char* s) 
{
```

You have no need to pass information back via variables passed in by reference.  Functions return values -- typically 'the answer'.

You're simply *scanning* the content of the argument string `s`, so there's no need to copy it anywhere.

As others have pointed out, you were scanning the contents of the array `c[]` before you copied anything in to it -- you were counting 'G' and 'C' in a (probably large) random block of memory.  Keeping things simple avoids mistakes like that.

```
    int nvalid = 0;
    int gccount = 0;
    float result;

    for (; *s != '\0'; s++) {
```

Although the `for` loop you wrote isn't *wrong*, it's somewhat un-idiomatic.  Here, we examine the character pointed to by the pointer `s`, and then increment the pointer, until we find ourselves pointing at the `\0` that terminates the string.  Yes, this means we 'lose' the initial value of the argument, but we don't need it after the loop, so that doesn't matter.

```
        switch (*s) {
```

A switch is a more natural construction here.  You're looking for a small set of possible values that `*s` (that is, the character the pointer is currently pointing at) may have.

```
          case 'G':
          case 'C':
            nvalid++;
            gccount++;
            break;

          case 'A':
          case 'T':
            nvalid++;
            break;

          default:
            /* unexpected character -- ignore it */
            break;
```

*Every* `switch` statement should have a `default` clause -- one should always think of what's supposed to happen if none of the `case` clauses match.  In this case, we just ignore this character.

```
        }
    }
    if (nvalid == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid letters found!\n");
        result = 0.0;
    } else {
        /* Multiply by 1.0 to convert integer gccount to a float */
        result = 1.0*gccount / nvalid;
    }
    return result;
```

We return the result to the caller rather than printing it out inside the function.  Functions shouldn't 'chatter', but leave all of the I/O in one place, typically leaving the main function (or something higher up) to look after that.

```
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        /* Give the user a hint on how to call the program */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: gcat <string>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Sequence GC-content = %g\n", count_gc(argv[1]));
}
```

I run that with:

```
% cc -o gcat gcat.c
% ./gcat "GCAT ATx foo"         
Sequence GC-content = 0.333333
%
```

With C, it's very easy to tie yourself in knots, very quickly.  Aim for simplicity always.